# Creating a temporary table name with a randomly generated number

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables, declare

So far I have this code:

```
declare @random int, @upper int, @lower int, @rndtb varchar(20)
set @lower = 1
set @upper = 999
select @random = ROUND(((@upper - @lower) * rand() + @lower),0)
select @rndtb = '##show'+cast(@random as varchar(20))+''
```

But that gives me

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '##show' to data type int.

What I am trying to achieve is to create a table ##show+random number each time the query is executed.

Example :

```
##show01
##show78
##show43
```

Edited with what @bluefeet said and found a way to create the table with

```
Declare @SQL VarChar(1000)

SELECT @SQL = 'Create Table ' + @rndtb + '('
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'ID int NOT NULL Primary Key, FieldName VarChar(10))'

Exec (@SQL)
```

but how do I call or insert into this table?

Comment: I feel like your question subject and question need cleaned up a bit... it's a bit all over the place.

Comment: By incorporating an answer into the question, you've made the post messy. For instance, you fixed the conversion issue but didn't remove the error message, and it now doesn't make sense. But if you did remove the message, then the entire question would probable make no sense, because it might no longer look like a question. Instead, if you wanted to show what you finally ended up with, you should have posted that as an *answer*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are adding the parameter `@random` to a string, you need to cast it as a varchar so it can be concatenated to the string portion:

```
select @rndtb = '##show'+cast(@random as varchar(20))+''
```

Your full code will be:

```
declare @random int, @upper int, @lower int, @rndtb varchar(20)
set @lower = 1
set @upper = 999
select @random = ROUND(((@upper - @lower) * rand() + @lower),0)
select @rndtb = '##show'+cast(@random as varchar(20))+''
```

Based on your edit, you will need to use dynamic sql to insert into the new table:

```
select @SQL = 'insert into '+@rndtb+'
        select *
        from yourtable'


exec (@sql)
```

Comment: And how can I select into the newly created table? ie. select top 5 into @rndtb from table1

Comment: @JohnZ see my edit, you will have to use dynamic sql to insert into the table.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
select @rndtb = '##show'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @random, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need dynamic SQL

The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html