# Creating a Random name (number) temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have been playing around with Dynamic SQL to try and accomplish this, and it is kinda possible, but not the smoothest way to go about it.

So I was wondering if there is a way to create a random name temp table (##show101, ##show24, ##show576).

What I am trying to achieve is a temp table is created with certain data in it from different tables. Then I just manipulate the data in the temp table and give an output.

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have one table with a unique ID column to contain your random number?  You could then just select records from the table with the appropriate ID.

Comment: A temporary table is scoped within a single dynamic SQL execute statement.  Why do you need to version it?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - Can't as the data inputed into the table varies based on what the client selects, so the columns differ

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I am sorry, but my SQL knowledge is not high enough to actually understand the question. I know that temp tables are only temp until the session is out. But like I said, I am not understanding the question

Comment: You have already asked exactly [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756780/creating-a-temporary-table-name-with-a-randomly-generated-number) and accepted an answer. What precisely is different about this question?

Comment: @Pondlife - Yes, and that's where I got all the dynamic code from, was just wondering if there is a whole different way or easier way to go about this, and Gordon has explained it to me in such way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is using *global* temporary tables.  These remain in place until they are deleted, and they can be shared between different connections.  That is why they are "global".  In your case, they can be shared between the execution of the dynamic statement and the outer statement.

I would suggest code that looks more like this:

```
create table #MyTempTable . . . <as whatever>

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '
    select <whatver>
    into #temp1

    . . .

    do some more work on #temp1 if you like

    --Finally
    select * from temp1
   ';

insert into #MyTempTable
    exec(@sql);
```

This will "move" the data from the dynamic scoping to the outer scoping, where you can use it for other purposes.  You can now access it in #MyTempTable.

Comment: Ok, this looks simple enough to use no problem, but how can I generate a random number at the end of #MyTempTable or is it not needed at all? What if two or more clients are running the query? They can only work with the #MyTempTable they created correct?

Comment: @JohnZ . . . The random number is not needed at all.  You can just use a local temp table.